# Re-render React descendant components without re-rendering ancestors

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a Navbar using React 16.8.3. I would like to use composition to pass the Navbar content instead of passing a config object via props, in order to have more flexibility. Something like this:

```html
<Navbar>
    <NavItem>Some label</NavItem>
    <NavItem>
        <span>Some arbitrary content</span>
    <NavItem>
</Navbar>
```

instead of:

```js
const navItems = [
  {
    label: 'Some label'
  },
  {
    label: 'Some other label'
  }
]

<Navbar items={navItems} />
```

So far the Navbar is working fine. I've added some logic in the shouldComponentUpdate method to prevent multiple re-renders:

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
   return nextProps.selectedItem !== this.props.selectedItem;
}
```

so the Navbar only re-renders when its selected item changes, and not, for instance, when the Navbar parent re-renders.

Problem is that one NavItem contains a badge with a task count that must be updated whenever the user does some tasks:

[Todos screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORpi6.png)

and the item markup is:

```html
<Navbar>
    <NavItem>
        <div className="has-badge">
           <span>Label</span>
           <span className="badge">{this.props.toDoCount}</span>
        </div>
    </NavItem>
</Navbar>
```

this.props.toDoCount **is a prop of the Navbar parent**, and not of the Navbar itself.

How can I update the badge number **without re-rendering the whole Navbar**?. So far I've tried creating a Badge component, adding some state, and a method to update the badge number using a ref in the Navbar parent:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

interface BadgeProps {
  number: number;
}

class Badge extends PureComponent<BadgeProps> {
  state = {
    number: 0
  };

  setCount(number) {
    this.setState({
      number
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <span className="badge">{this.state.number}</span>;
  }
}
```

In the Navbar parent:

```js
private todos = createRef<Badge>();

...

componentDidUpdate(prevProps: EhrProps) {    
   this.todos.current.setCount(toDosCount);
}
```

and it's working, but... is there an easier or cleaner way of doing this in React??

Thanks!

PS: We are using Redux in the project, but I would like to avoid using the store in the Navbar or its items.

**EDIT:**

I'm using React.children and React.cloneElement in the Navbar's render method:

```js
render() {
    const { className, children, selectedItem, ...rest } = this.props;
    const classes = classNames(
      {
        navbar: true
      },
      className
    );

    return (
      <nav className={classes} {...rest}>
        {React.Children.map(children, child => {
          if (child.type === NavItem) {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
              onClick: this.handleItemClick,
              selected: child.props.name === selectedItem
            });
          }
          return child;
        })}
      </nav>
    );
  }
```

And each NavItem handles its own render:

```js
return (
    <div className={classes} onClick={handleClick} onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} role="menuitem" tabIndex={0}>
      {children}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have some code for the the `Navbar` component that looks a bit like this.

```
class Navbar extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.navItem.map(item => <NavItem key={item.label}>{item.label}</NavItem>)};
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and then some code to render each child `NavItem`.

To make the component fairly efficient, it's sufficient to have the whole of Navbar rerender, but only not re-render each child.

What I would recommend is:

1. Make each child of Navbar be rendered in its own component; in the component above it's called `NavItem`
2. Use either `componentShouldUpdate` or [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) (look into this! Once you understand it, it's a great general solution to use by default instead of React.Component for every component) to make sure that each child only re-renders when its value changes

What will happen when you update the badge for the single NavItem is that `Navbar` will re-render. Most of the `NavItems` will see their Props haven't changed, and not re-render. The  single child of `Navbar` that has the badge will have changed, and will re-render. With this, the real overhead is actually quite low.

If your `Navbar` has a ton of children or your badge for that single child changes a lot, you can probably optimize it more by using `React.Context` or Redux to pass in the value for that single child, but that feels messy and seems like premature optimization.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I'm using React.children and React.cloneElement in the Navbar's render method (see edit) so the content is rendered using props.children.